# Ti.App.iOS `continueactivity` not working on production build

Tags: appcelerator, ios-universal-links

I have a Titanium app that's handling an incoming [Universal Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) by capturing the iOS `continueactivity` event. This is the code I have:

```
if(OS_IOS){
    Ti.App.iOS.addEventListener('continueactivity', function(e){
        if(e.activityType === "NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb"){
            handleURL(e.webpageURL);
        }
    });
}
```

This code works perfectly while the app is being debugged but it seems like the event is not fired on the production build.

any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I just confirmed that this is also happening on the Ti Example App with SDK 5.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and was reported here:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20220

It has been fixed for version 5.4.0.